# Are the irreducible representations of $U(n)$ the same as $SU(n)$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, orthogonal-matrices, unitary-matrices

I am interested to know whether $U(n)$ has the same (irreducible) representations as $SU(n)$ and why? I have noticed that very often in the literature there is not a clear distinction between these two. The same observation applies for other groups such as $SO(n)$, $O(n)$ and $Sp(2n)$ with $USp(2n)$.

Comment: They are not the same (but closely related). For instance, you can take an irreducible representation of $SU(n)$ to $GL(V)$ and extend it to a representation $U(n)\to GL(V)$ using a nontrivial character of $S^1$: The center of $U(n)$ modulo the center of $SU(n)$.

Comment: The extra U(1) in the center of U(N) distinguishing it from SU(N) for most practical purposes is easy to deal with separately on top of the SU(N) irreps... it is an extra phase.